# PHPMyADMIN - mysql show foreign key constraints #1216 - Magento 2 Database

Tags: magento

On localhost i export a magento 2 database using phpmyadmin and try to upload on our server but it giving us error of #1216 - Foreign key constraints. The problem is TABLE A define first in sql and try to create Table B field as Foreign key. So if TABLE B is not creating then giving Foreign key error and not creating database. When i am doing same using command prompt it is working fine. So using phpmyadmin through the error ? Can any one please help me on it?

Answer (score 0):

To solve this use the checkbox `Disable Foreign Key` Checks when exporting from `PhpMyadmin`. Or set it yourself:

```
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0;
```

and at the end:

```
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=1;
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Can you please share where can i get Disable Foreign Key in PHPmyADMIN?

Comment: While exporting the database select "custom" as export method. It will show you various options, from those options check the "Disable foreign key" option.

Comment: Thanks Gaurav! I got it.